# Apps failed to build when embed in workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, xcode-workspace

I have 3 projects:

- my custom developed framework 'XXX.framework' (that have dependency on 3rd party 'YYY.framework'). Both frameworks have different versions for real devices and for simulator, thus they differ by arch they build for
- 2 demo apps in Objc-C 'DemoObjC.app' and Swift 'DemoSw.app' that use my 'XXX.framework'.

I linked my custom 'XXX.framework' to those 2 demo apps which separately build and run normally.

But when I embed 3 projects into workspace to work on all of the projects at same time in one window, I face with strange behaviour. Sometimes I can't run apps on device or simulator. By that I mean sometimes it builds and runs normally, but then without any changes it fails. Or it can run normally for simulator but not for real device, but after XCode relaunch it might happen that it already can run for device but not for Simulator.
I tried to clean project, delete DerivedData, relaunch XCode, and reboot, but it helps only for several successful runs, after that I still get unexpected behavior.

For example, in workspace I try to run 'DemoObjC.app' on device and I get

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Path_Here/SIMULATOR/YYY.framework/YYY, 
missing required architecture arm64 in file /Path_Here/SIMULATOR/YYY.framework/YYY, (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
<List of files that can't be find>
```

I can't understand why it fails on SIMULATOR when I run it on device? Project and target are seems to be configured fine because separate projects build and run normally.

Or here is error when I try to run on simulator:

```
ignoring file /Path_Here/NOT_A_SIMULATOR/YYY.framework/YYY, 
missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Path_Here/NOT_A_SIMULATOR/YYY.framework/YYY (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

Same issues in XCode 8.2 and 8.2.1

Any glues what is wrong? I lean toward that it is XCode related issue.

Comment: Looks like you didn't add x86_64 architecture in your framework. To run on the simulator you have to add that architecture. I mean you have to add all architectures to make a framework and work all devices.

Comment: No, architectures are correct, if not they would not run when open like single projects. Plus `lipo` says the same:
----
mb-000357:sid$ cd /Path_Here/NOT_A_SIMULATOR/YYY.framework/YYY 
    mb-000357:sid$ xcrun lipo -info YYY
Architectures in the fat file: YYY are: armv7 arm64 
mb-000357:sid$ cd /Path_Here/SIMULATOR/YYY.framework/YYY 
mb-000357:sid$ xcrun lipo -info YYY
Architectures in the fat file: YYY are: i386 x86_64
----